# Como estabelecer conexão socket SSL/TSL com NodeJS

Tags: node.js, segurança, socket, ssl, certificado-digital

criei um servidor socket bem simples com NodeJS (v8.11.3) e está funcionando OK aparentemente. Meu objetivo é manter uma conexão socket aberta continuamente com um dispositivo eletrônico (IoT).

PERGUNTA: Como tornar a comunicação segura, ou seja, como fazer uma comunicação socket SSL/TLS com socket?
OBS.: também criei um certificado auto-assinado para testes.

O servidor socket de teste (sem segurança) é esse abaixo. Como não tenho experiência com NodeJS imagino que existam formas bem melhores...

```
const net = require('net')

net.createServer(socket => {
    socket.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log('Socket Error: ')
        console.log(err.stack)
    })

    socket.on('data', function(data){
        msg = ''
        msg = data.toString();
        socket.write(msg)
        console.log(msg)
    })
}).listen(8001)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/*
    DOCUMENTAÇÃO DE REFERÊNCIA:
    https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createserver_options_secureconnectionlistener
    https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_connect_options_callback

    Este exemplo foi criado com base em um certificado auto-assinado e  
    devem ser alterados os paths dos arquivos, indicando a pasta correta.
*/

const tls = require('tls');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
    //key: fs.readFileSync('server-key.pem'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('utils/51952868_localhost.key'),
    //cert: fs.readFileSync('server-cert.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('utils/51952868_localhost.cert'),

    // This is necessary only if using client certificate authentication.
    //requestCert: true,

    // This is necessary only if the client uses a self-signed certificate.
    //ca: [ fs.readFileSync('client-cert.pem') ]
};

const server = tls.createServer(options, (socket) => {
    console.log('Cliente ' + socket.remoteAddress + ':' + socket.remotePort);

    socket.write('Welcome from Server!\n');

    // Trata a recepção dos dados enviados pelo Cliente
    socket.on('data', function(data){
        msg = ''
        msg = data.toString();
        socket.write(msg)
        console.log(msg)
    })

    // Trata o evento de DESCONEXÃO do Cliente corrente
    socket.on('end', () => {
        console.log('Desconectado!') 
    })

    // Trata todas as condições de ERRO do sistema
    socket.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log('Socket Error: ')
        console.log(err.stack)
    })

});

// Inicia o servidor usando a porta "443" (escolha do usuário)
server.listen(443, () => {
    console.log('Servidor em execução!');
});
```